# How do I Populate Access 2007 ComboBox with another combobox using Nested Sets table

Tags: sql, combobox, nested-sets

Hi I have a nested sets table used to store 5 layers of departments in a tree like structure.  I have been able to populate one combo box in Access 2007 with the following query.

SELECT Child.name1, Child.lft, Child.rgt
FROM PROGRAMS AS Child, PROGRAMS AS Parent
WHERE Child.Depth=Parent.Depth+1 And Child.lft>Parent.lft And Child.rgt

I have the following code in the change event of the first combobox trying to populate the 2nd on the change event.

```
Private Sub cmbDpmt1_Change()

    Dim strSql As String
    Dim strDpmtLevel1 As String
    strDpmtLevel1 = Me.cmbDpmt1.Text

    strSql = "SELECT Child.name1, Child.lft, Child.rgt FROM PROGRAMS AS Child, PROGRAMS          AS Parent WHERE Child.Depth = Parent.Depth+1 And Child.lft > Parent.lft And Child.rgt <   Parent.rgt And Parent.name1 = " & strDpmtLevel1 & " " & "ORDER BY child.lft;"

    Me.cmbDpmt2.RowSource = strSql
    Me.Requery

End Sub
```

I am able to get the query to work without error in database without the form itself just fine.  However when I try to use the form change event in vba this way it asks for another parameter to fill out where it should just populate the second combobox based on the selected text from the first.

Basically the result should be next level of children from the department selected in the first combo box.

Is there something I am missing here? Why would it ask for another parameter when all are filled?